# How to get the value of the x variable?

Tags: java, android

```
public static void test(int x, int y) {

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    };
    thread.start();

}
```

This is my code. I can't get value of **x**. How do I get the value of the parameter x in the method of the anonymous class of the function?

Comment: I think x must be declared `final` in order to use it in the anonymous class function!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare parameter `x` final

```
   public static void test(final int x, int y) {

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        };
        thread.start();

    }
```